# select is not defined, jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was practicing with data picker in jQuery UI and I got into problem that I could't solve.

I wanted to calculate the difference of given date (from date picker) and today's date in days, after user clicked calculate button.

I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: select is not defined(anonymous
    function)
j
k.fireWithjQuery.js: 2
m.extend.readyjQuery.js: 2
J
```

Here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#calculate").click(function() {
            var d1 = $(".date-pick").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
            var d2 = $("#startDate").datepicker('getDate');
            var diff = 0;
            if (d1 && d2) {
                diff = Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000);
            }
            $('#calculated').val(diff);
        });
        $("#startDate").datepicker({
            onSelect: select
        });
    });
```

[Here is my complete source code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nbgbjdvl0wqf4kv/AABwlovIfeQGSu6IMjXRtZySa?dl=0)

Comment: It's not defined because you didn't define it anywhere, you just randomly typed `select` as a value in an object, and there's no variable named `select` in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply have not defined `select` function anywhere in your source code (all your custom js-code is currently in your *index.html*, so it is easy to figure it out), but you are trying to use it as `onSelect` event handler.

Comment: I followed this example: http://jsfiddle.net/MebwN/49/ It also didn't define select.

Comment: @Apha but in example you mention `select` function is explicitly defined.

Comment: @Apha: Yes it did.  `var select = function(dateStr){`